# Minecraft (Java): Changing a name of player?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

So, my program isn't working.  I'm trying to make it so when someone does /nick [nick], it'll change their name in the chat.  This is my current code for the command.  What am I doing wrong?

```
p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', args[0]));
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you invoke `ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', args[0])`? How is it related to `setDisplayName`?

Comment: I was trying to make it so the colour codes are accepted using &.

Comment: It would be easier to understand the question if you included the color in your question or took the color out of your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should show us more code, and tell us where is the wrong happened.or nobody can help you.

Second, some plugin can overwrite your plugin's set, you can try run the server without other plugins.